# Lost Mail when removed pop account to re-add as imap account

Tags: mail.app, data-recovery

I removed an mail account from the mail application because it was configured as pop and had to be imap. Now I have lost my mail which was stored locally. I have read about [iskysoft data recovery](http://www.iskysoft.us/lp/data-recovery-mac/), but that tool has a folder structure which is huge. So I am clicking around in folders to see if there is any mail from 2011 etc.

I am not so familiar with Mac OS X and the mail application. These are times when you would want to have an up-to-date timecapsule backup, but that one is from november 2013 :S

Can you suggest a better mail recovery tool or a manual recovery? Or tell me that this is the right tool and that this will solve all my problems and will put back the lost e-mails in the Mail application.

[image]

I have just read about disk drill. but that is no option for me (I think) because I should have used 'recovery vault' first. before removing the pop3 account. http://help.cleverfiles.com/mailbox-recovery-2/

Comment: You said you are unfamiliar with it but are you familiar enough with Time Machine and have that set up? Additionally check your user folder's Library folder (Menu bar > Go > and while holding the alt/option key you should see Library). In the Library folder you should see a folder called Mail. How big is that folder and what is inside of it?

Comment: V2 = 5.6 gb it has to imap folders, one mailboxes and one maildata. iskysoft shows a lot of folders with *.eimx files

Comment: under Mailboxes is there a folder or mbox called Local or POP...?

Comment: there is outbox.mbox, imported.mbox and deleted messages.mbox

Comment: And no Time Machine set up?

Comment: it is, but as I said, last backup was from november... the iskysoft shows mail from 2010 somewhere in the deleted folders... but unsure if that is the correct mail.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have a hard time recovering the files and should power off the machine / only mount that drive in read-only mode until you have given up on the idea of data recovery.

I like [Data Rescue](http://www.prosofteng.com/products/data_rescue.php) 3 - but your tool will probably be mostly equivalent.

Look to recover `~/Library/Mail` and `~/Library/Mail Downloads` files if possible. Ideally you can get the computer friendly - human hostile directory structure back and recover all files with these extensions intact:

- emlx
- plist

Comment: is this the correct data rescue https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/10259/data-rescue

Comment: Yes - I added a link to the vendor site above.

Answer (score 0):

According to an apple expert:

> it cannot be recovered because it is an Apple Macbook air with an SSD drive which uses [trim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trim_%28computing%29).

so the only option left was to restore mbox files from the 2 months old timecapsule backup. He took them from the ~/library/mail/v2 etc. folder.

Apple should change mail to allow it to remove the pop3 account and keep the mail and/or if it has to remove the mails, move it to the trash can so it can be restored.

another article about ssd and trim: http://help.cleverfiles.com/can-i-recover-data-if-trim-is-enabled-on-my-ssd-drive/